# How can I share an excel document with a large group users as read-only?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I have our schedule in an excel document that is shared to all the employees via sharepoint.  I would like to set it up so that me and a couple other managers have write access to the excel sheet, and everyone else only has read access.

Currently we have the excel sheet password protected, but would prefer to have it so that we don't have to open it in excel to make changes, but instead edit directly via Sharepoint.  Is this possible in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via granting unique permissions on the excel document.

- Go to Microsoft 365 admin center, create a group with managers added and a group with users added.
- Click the ellipsis next to the document -> Manage access -> Advanced.
  [image]

[image]

- Click "Stop inheriting Permissions" in the ribbon.
- Click "Grant Permissions", grant managers group with Edit permission level and users group with Read permission level.
  [image]